# In Spring Batch how to run 2 select queries one after the other and I have to pass first query result to the second query

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm new to spring batch. My first query returns a client id which has to be used in the second query to retrieve the results. Also I need to have both these queries in ItemReaders

I have tried the below way:

First itemReader:

```
@Component
public class ClientItemReader extends RepositoryItemReader<Client>{

private ClientRepository clientRepository;
private StepExecution stepExecution;

@BeforeStep
private void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}

public ClientItemReader(ClientRepository clientRepository) {
    this.clientRepository= clientRepository;
    super.setRepository(clientRepository);
    super.setMethodName("findAll");
    super.setPageSize(500);
}

@Override
public Client read()
        throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException { 
    Client client= super.read();
    ExecutionContext stepExecutionContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    stepExecutionContext.put("clientId", client.getClientId());
    return client;
}       
}
```

Second itemReader:

```
@Component
public class BillItemReader extends 
RepositoryItemReader<Bill>{

private BillRepository billRepository;
public static final String REPO_METHOD_NAME = "findByClientId";
private StepExecution stepExecution;

@BeforeStep
private void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}

public BillItemReader(BillRepository billRepository) {
    this.billRepository= billRepository;
    super.setRepository(billRepository);
    super.setMethodName(REPO_METHOD_NAME);
}

@Override
public Bill read()
        throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, 
NonTransientResourceException {
    ExecutionContext executionContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    if(executionContext.containsKey("clientId")) { 
       super.setArguments(Collections.singletonList
       (executionContext.getLong("clientId")));
       return super.read();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Custom itemReader:

```
@Component
public class ClientBillItemReader implements ItemReader<List<Bill>>{

private final ClientItemReader clientItemReader;
private final BillItemReader billItemReader;

public ClientBillItemReader (ClientItemReader clientItemReader, 
BillItemReader billItemReader) {
    this.clientItemReader= clientItemReader;
    this.billItemReader= billItemReader;
}

@Override
public List<Bill> read()
        throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, 
NonTransientResourceException {
    List<Bill> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Client client= clientItemReader.read();
    Bill bill= billItemReader.read();
    items.add(bill);
    while(bill != null && Objects.equal(client.getBisId(), 
    bill.getClientId())) {
        bill = billItemReader.read();
        items.add(bill);
    }
    return items;
}
}
```

Job config:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientBillJobConfig {

private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
private final ClientBillItemReader itemReader;
private final ClientBillItemProcessor itemProcessor;
private final ClientBillItemWriter itemWriter;

public ClientBillJobConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, 
StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ClientBillItemReader itemReader, 
ClientBillItemProcessor itemProcessor, ClientBillItemWriter 
itemWriter) {
    this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
    this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
    this.itemReader = itemReader;
    this.itemProcessor = itemProcessor;
    this.itemWriter= itemWriter;
}

@Bean
public Step createClientBillStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step"). 
<List<Bill>, 
clientBillResponse>chunk(1000).reader(itemReader)
.processor(itemProcessor).writer(itemWriter).build();
}

@Bean
public Job clientBillJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobName").incrementer(new 
    RunIdIncrementer()).flow(createClientBillStep()).end().build();
}
}
```

I'm getting following exception
 `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ClientBillJobConfig' defined in file [C:\Source\xyz\bin\main\com\xyz\client\config\ClientBillJobConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ClientItemReader' defined in file [C:\Source\xyz\bin\main\com\xyz\client\job\reader\ClientItemReader.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A sort is required`

Comment: how about? https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Comment: Hello. I have trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need to get all the client ids first ? Do you just want to check that the client ID of the bill exists ?

Comment: It sasys "Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A sort is required". Have you checked this?

Answer (score 0):

Is is written in the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A sort is required

You need to use [setSort()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemReader.html#setSort-java.util.Map-)

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly says

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: A sort is required`

Try adding sort to both the readers `ClientItemReader` and `BillItemReader`.

```
Map<String, Sort.Direction> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("<field-name>", Sort.Direction.ASC);
super.setSort(map);
```

Hope this helps!